# creating parent child relationship when migrating data (sql server 2008)

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Background**

I am migrating data from a client and they came in csv format.I import all the data in staging database ,so far so good.

**Now**

I need to move this data with a series of script from this Staging Database to another database using sql scripts.

As usual this data has not got proper primary key and foreign key ,so it's up to me to create some sort of relationship

Let's take an example Given 2 tables Customer and CustomerOrder how do I Insert/create the relationship between the two?
How do I insert the Id from the customer table into the CustomerOrder table?

I have to do this for many tables so I want to establish a way of doing it!

**tables**

```
        IF object_id(N'Customer', 'U') IS NOT NULL
            DROP TABLE Customer

        GO
        CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer](
            [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
            [Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
            [Surname] [varchar](50) NULL,
         CONSTRAINT [PK_Customer] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
        (
            [Id] ASC
        )
        ) ON [PRIMARY]


        IF object_id(N'CustomerOrder', 'U') IS NOT NULL
            DROP TABLE CustomerOrder

        GO
        CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CustomerOrder](
            [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
            [CustomerId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
            [OrderNo] [bigint] NULL,
            [OrderName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
         CONSTRAINT [PK_CustomerOrder] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
        (
            [Id] ASC
        )
        ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**try to insert data from staging db to mydb**

```
        Insert MyDatabase.dbo.Customer
        (   --Id - this column value is auto-generated
            Name,
            Surname
        )
        Select Name,Surname
        from StagingDatabase.dbo.Customer

        INSERT MyDatabase.dbo.CustomerOrder
        (
            --Id - this column value is auto-generated
            CustomerId,
            OrderNo,
            OrderName
        )
        SELECT CustomerId=???,OrderNo,OrderNo
        FROM StagingDatabase
```

When you are faced with bad data and you need to create and insert parent/child data how do you do it?

Any suggestions?

Comment: How is the data structured in the staging table?

Comment: The staging and "myDb" have the same structure

Comment: What I meant was, what does the data look like before you import into the staging table, and what does it look like in the staging table? Can you provide a few example rows? How do you tell to which customer a order belong?

Comment: The customer and the order in their raw format are in the same row.But  when I move into myDB i need to create a Customer Row and Order row in their respective table.So if I create a record in the Customer Table and I assign a CustomerID(Autogenerated by sql server) how can I assign that same key to the order table. The question maybe is "How do you insert the data in these 2 tables and creating a relationship on the fly".I can make up a couple of rows if helps

Comment: The only thing I can thing of is doing it in a cursor but I want to avoid using a cursor.For each customer get the last identity inserted and create the CustomerOrder using the last identity inserted into the customer.There must be a better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Populate the `Customer` table.** (These queries assume autogenerated primary keys).

```
insert into Customer (Name,Surname)
    select Name,Surname from staging_table;
```

**Populate the `CustomerOrders` table.** Join to `Customer` using the non-primary key fields to get the primary key.

```
insert into CustomerOrders (CustomerId,OrderNo,OrderName)
    select cust.Id, OrderNo, OrderName
        from staging_table staging
        join Customer cust on
            cust.Name    = staging.Name and
            cust.Surname = staging.Surname;
```

Join on all fields that are required to uniquely identify a customer.  Obviously name alone is generally not sufficient for this, but I am assuming this is only an example.

Also, if any fields can be null, you have to handle that specially in the joining.  Otherwise, rows with nulls will be omitted:

```
 join customer cust on
    coalesce(cust.Name,'**NULL**') = coalesce(staging.Name,'**NULL**') and
    ... etc. ...
```

It doesn't matter what string you use in the `coalesce`, as long as it is something that will never appear in the actual data.

Comment: sorry for silly question.Could you show me with a sql snippet what you mean

Comment: that sounds good I will give it a try and let you know. The only thing I could come up with was using a cursor eg 1)insert the customer ,2)get ScopeIdentity() and then insert customerorder but that would be too slow i suppose